# Firebase Google Login Popup Button

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

Easy question I'm sure for people more familiar with javascript than myself.  Anyways using polymer started kit with google authentication enabled through Firebase app.  Problem is I do not want an automatic popup asked to login.  I need this action to be invoked when a button is clicked.  I've researched and have been able to get various example javascript functions to work with a button but I just can't seem to get it with the provided firebase code.  It's as follows below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com')
ref.authWithOAuthPopup('google', function(error, authData) {  
  ;
  if (error) {
console.log('Login Failed!', error);
  } else {
console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
  }

  });
```

Comment: check out my extended set and the associated demo: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended

Comment: Thanks! How do I go about mimicking your demo function?  I cloned the project and uploaded to firebase but I must be missing something still. https://polylogin1.firebaseapp.com/app/